# How to stop recursion after returning from method

Tags: java, recursion

I have a program which makes call to a functin which is recursive.

```
int dd=dis(root,2,0);
```

Function code

```
   public int dis(Node n,int g,int count)
   {
    if(g==n.data)
    {
        System.out.println("equal count"+count);
        return count;
    }
    
    else if(g>n.data)
    {
        count=count+1;
        dis(n.right,g,count);
    }
    
    else if(g<n.data)
    {   
        count=count+1;
        dis(n.left,g,count);
    }
    System.out.println("function"+count);
    return count;
}
```

When the data equals node value, the function returns count, the exact value I needed. However, the recursion continues after count is returned, and returns the abnormal count value at the end of function.

I want to totally back out of the function after count is returned from == case, I dont want recursion to modify the value in the calling function after first count has been returned.

Comment: This would be simpler using iteration, this is just recursion applied for the sake of recursion.

Comment: @Esailija: I disagree; I think recursion, done properly, is actually the simplest and most intuitive way to navigate a binary tree.

Comment: @ruakh what does that have to with the OP's code?

Comment: @Esailija: I don't understand your question. The OP's code is navigating a binary search tree, and returning a count of how "deep" it had to go to find a given element. (Right?) I'm saying that I think recursion is the simplest and most intuitive way to do that. Are we miscommunicating somehow?

Comment: @ruakh I am saying the op's code would be simpler expressed as iteration. It would only eliminate 1 parameter and passing g and count around but nevertheless simpler and probably would have avoided his problem to begin with.

Comment: @Esailija: That's because the OP's code is not the simplest way to write this recursively. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ruakh yes that is simpler :)

Comment: thanks for the updated code, its way cool and neat :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this:

```
        dis(n.right,g,count);
```

to this:

```
        return dis(n.right,g,count);
```

and this:

```
        dis(n.left,g,count);
```

to this:

```
        return dis(n.left,g,count);
```

---

**Edited to add:** A simpler way to write this function might be:

```
public int dis(final Node n, final int g)
{
    if(g == n.data)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + dis(g < n.data ? n.left : n.right, g);
}
```

Note that in this approach, the `count` variable completely disappears: from an imperative/procedural standpoint, you might say that rather than counting the nodes as you descend into the tree, this approach counts them as it returns back out. (But it's better to look at it from a functional/recursive standpoint, and say that if the depth of `g` in the appropriate subtree is `n`, then its depth in the parent tree is one greater.)

The simplest imperative version is probably:

```
public int dis(final Node root, final int g)
{
    int depth = 0;
    for(Node n = root; g != n.data; n = (g < n.data ? n.left : n.right))
        ++depth;
    return depth;
}
```

Comment: That worked, so instead of returning from the original func, we return from the recursive call. Am I right?

Comment: @user2133404: The function is declared as returning `int`, so it must *always* return, whether or not it's a recursive call. The question is simply *what* it returns. And keep in mind that each call has a completely separate `count` variable; if one call changes its `count`, that won't affect the value of `count` in any other call. Do you see what I mean?